# Google AppsScript Connecting to Firestore

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query a collection in my firestore with the following code. This code is designed to get all the firestore documents after a certain timestamp:

```
function populateSheetFromFirestore() {
  var weekNumber = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('weekNumber');
  weekNumber = weekNumber ? parseInt(weekNumber) : 0;

  var newSpreadsheetName = 'Week ' + (weekNumber + 1);

  var templateSpreadsheetId = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
  var currentTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
  var lastTemplateCreationTimestamp = parseInt(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('lastTemplateCreationTimestamp'));
  var lastProcessedDocTimestamp = parseInt(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('lastProcessedDocTimestamp'));

  if (!lastTemplateCreationTimestamp || currentTimestamp - lastTemplateCreationTimestamp >= 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
    // Create a new template spreadsheet
    var newSpreadsheet = DriveApp.getFileById(templateSpreadsheetId).makeCopy(newSpreadsheetName);
    var newSpreadsheetId = newSpreadsheet.getId();

    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('lastTemplateSpreadsheetId', newSpreadsheetId);
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('lastTemplateCreationTimestamp', currentTimestamp);
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('weekNumber', weekNumber + 1);
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('lastProcessedDocTimestamp', 0);
  } else {
    var newSpreadsheetId = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('lastTemplateSpreadsheetId');
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newSpreadsheetId).getActiveSheet();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

  // Initialize Firebase Admin SDK (replace 'YOUR_JSON_KEY.json' with the path to your JSON key file)
  var firebaseKeyFile = 'XXXXXXXXX';
  var firebaseAdmin = FirebaseAdminSdk.initializeApp({
    credential: FirebaseAdminSdk.credential.cert(firebaseKeyFile),
    databaseURL: 'https://PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com' // Replace with your Firebase project URL
  });

  var firestore = firebaseAdmin.firestore();
  var collectionName = 'Provider_Invoice_Submissions';

  // Construct a Firestore query to get documents with updatedAt greater than the last processed timestamp
  var query = firestore.collection(collectionName)
    .where('updatedAt', '>', new Date(lastProcessedDocTimestamp).toISOString())
    .orderBy('updatedAt');

  query.get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        var data = doc.data();
        var updatedAtTimestamp = new Date(data.updatedAt).getTime();

        var rowData = [
          data.name,
          data.email,
          data['Date Worked'],
          data['Shift Start Time'],
          data['Shift End Time'],
          data['Overtime'],
          data['Location'],
          data['Hours worked'],
          data['Comments']
        ];

        sheet.appendRow(rowData);

        PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('lastProcessedDocTimestamp', updatedAtTimestamp);
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      Logger.log('Error fetching documents: ', error);
    });
}
```

ERROR:
TypeError: collection is not a function
populateSheetFromFirestore  @ Code.gs:49

This is the error I keep receiving.

I tried adding the AppsScript API. I have my firestore istance correctly. For some reason i am not able to do this.

Comment: Can you provide your whole script by removing your personal information?

Comment: I updated to have the entire script

Comment: Can you verify that you have initialized Firebase Admin SDK correctly?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your showing script, can I ask you about the details of `FirebaseAdminSdk` in your showing script? Is that a library that can be used with Google Apps Script?